# How do i use the Wait mechanism in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

1. I am writing Selenium 2 + C# and Nunit for a J2EE application with JSF.
2. Probably since it is Ajax based, or network latency, Selenium fails unless i keep some 'wait' mechanism. I have listed the 4 ways i am trying them. However, there are still some cases where the test hangs, or says it could not get the element, or the element is stale. These errors are random and not consistent.
3. So i keep reducing the waits to alleviate staleness, or increase waits to enable element handling. Of course sometimes i wait for an inordinately long time.
4. I keep mixing up the various ways since they are a black art to me.Is there something wrong with the methods listed below ?

Thanks.

A) Waiting for progress bar

```
public void WaitForProgressBar(ref Screenshot ss, WebDriverWait wait, ref IWebElement progressBar, ref IWebDriver _driver)
            {
            try
                {
                progressBar = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
                {
                    return d.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@id='_viewRoot:status.start']/img[@src='images/pleasewait.gif']"));
                });
                }
            catch
                {
                _logger.Debug("Could not locate progress bar");
                }

            progressBar = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@id='_viewRoot:status.start']/img[@src='images/pleasewait.gif']"));
            while (progressBar.Displayed)
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

            _logger.Debug("Sleeping");

            while (progressBar.Displayed)
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);

            ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)_driver).GetScreenshot();
            ss.SaveAsFile("C:/WaitingForProgressBar.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            }
```

B) Sleep and then call the WaitForProgressBar()

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500);
logInAndConfigureHospital.WaitForProgressBar(ref ss, wait, ref progressBar, ref _driver);
```

C) Call WaitForProgressBar() and then sleep

```
logInAndConfigureHospital.WaitForProgressBar(ref ss, wait, ref progressBar, ref _driver);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
```

D) Use Wait Until

```
IWebElement checkBoxSelectAll = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
        {
            return d.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='convertHandlerForm:ConvertHandlerLines_header']/table/tbody/tr/td/input"));
        });
        checkBoxSelectAll.Click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two statements

```
while (progressBar.Displayed)
```

will throw `StaleElementReferenceException` as soon as the progress bar goes away, since the DOM has changed.

You need a method that handles the different exceptions when trying to check for the progress bar visibility.The below extension method does just that, and returns `null` value if element is not found, or if an exception is thrown.

```
public static class WebDriverExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Wait Get an element. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="driver"></param>
    /// <param name="by"></param>
    /// <param name="timeout">timeout in seconds to wait for element</param>
    /// <returns>the element, else null</returns>
    public static IWebElement WaitGetElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, 
            int timeout = 10, bool checkForVisibility=false)
    {
        IWebElement element;
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
        wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(StaleElementReferenceException));
        wait.Message = string.Format("Timed out after waiting {0} seconds for the {1} field ", timeout, by.ToString());
        try
        {
            if (checkForVisibility)
            {
                element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(by));
            }
            else
            {
                element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(by));
            }
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException) { element = null; }
        catch (WebDriverTimeoutException) { element = null; }
        catch (TimeoutException) { element = null; }

        return element;
    }
}
```

Now you can use the above extension method to wait for the progress bar using the below method. This will wait for a minimum of 1 sec for the progress bar to go away.

```
public bool WaitForProgressComplete(int waitTimeoutInSecs = 60)
{
   bool isComplete = false;
   var sw = new Stopwatch();
   sw.Start();
   while (!isComplete && sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds < waitTimeoutInSecs)
   {
      //try locate the progress bar, checking for max 1 sec(internally polls every 500ms) 
      //Check for visibility true (last param)
   progressBar = this.Driver.WaitGetElement(By.XPath("//span[@id='_viewRoot:status.start']/img[@src='images/pleasewait.gif']"), 1, true);
      isComplete = (progressBar == null);
   }

   sw.Stop();
   return isComplete;
}
```

The only caveat here is that if the progress bar takes less than 1 second to initially display, this method will return before the bar has been displayed. In this case, you can increase the wait timeout in the `WaitGetElement` call, or put a static wait beforehand.